# Rewriting regular expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, regular-expressions

For the following two regular expressions, how would I rewrite them as a simpler expression representing the same set?

1. $b^* \cup a^* \cup (a \cup b)^*$
2. $\Big((a^*b^*)^*(b^* \cup a^*)^*\Big)^*$

I am completely lost and really need some guidance. From what I've gathered, I know that the * operator represents the kleene star. So in this case, a* and b* are all sets of strings, including the empty string, that can be constructed from the alphabet a and b. I also understand how a Union operation works, but I have no clue as to how to begin simplifying these expressions. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Well, $a^*$ is the set of strings that consist only of $a$s, and $b^*$ is the set of strings that consist only of $b$s. On the other hand $(a\cup b)^*$ is the set of strings of letters that may each be either $a$ or $b$. Does something strike you as superfluous taking the union of those three sets?

Comment: Yeah, it does actually when you explain it that way... You could simply just have (a U b)*, correct?

Comment: x @James: Correct.

Comment: You rock mate! Could you also explain number 2 for me?

Comment: @James: For (2), ask yourelf: Is there any string that *isn’t* of the form $(a^*b^*)^*$? Is there any string that *isn’t* of the form $(b^*\cup a^*)^*$?

Comment: Would it be (a* b*)?

Comment: @James: No, that gives you only the strings of the form $a^mb^n$, where $m,n\ge 0$. How did you answer my two questions? (If you start your comment with `@Brian`, I’ll receive notification of it and probably respond a lot quicker.)

Comment: @Brian Ahhh, I'm so confused. I don't think I mentioned you. Kind of new to this site haha. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @James: No problem; I figured that you might not know.

Comment: @James, Brian asked two excellent hint-questions. Actually answering them will bring you closer to solving the problems.

Comment: @Brian, for your first question I came up with (a b) and for your second question I came up with (b U a)*.

Comment: @James: Do you mean that the expressions are equivalent to these? If so, you’re right about the second one: $(b^*\cup a^*)^*$ represents every string over $\{a,b\}$. But you’re not right about the first: show that it also represents every string over $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: I've been trying this same problem for the past 3 hours... I'm really beat down now. Could you please solve it while also explaining/rationalizing what steps you're taking to arrive at the solution? I'm about ready to call it a night.